# How to overlay graphics over table?

Tags: android, graphics, android-tablelayout

I have an interface that is a table with 3x3 group of icons (pretty numbers `ImageView`s) scaled to fit the display. My view structure is:

```
TableLayout
Row - Header graphic
Row - horizontal separator
Row - 3 buttons
Row - 3 buttons
Row - 3 buttons
Row - horizontal separator
Row - scroll view of buttons
```

When the user selects an icon, I highlight it with a background graphic.

I want to add overlays over each button to show progress, such as we get in many games showing stars for achievement. eg. Show the "4" icon for level 4 and overlay it with 1, 2, or 3 stars depending on how well it was accomplished. I can't figure out how to do this! There's only one graphic option in an `ImageView`.

Comment: Could you not create a graphic for each possiblescenario i.e. 1,2,3 or 4 stars and load the appropriate image as required?

Comment: Yes, but that would add considerably to download size.

Comment: I don't think it would add considerably. How big are the bitmaps going to be for a Button image?

Comment: Also look at using a Level list to select which image is shown. I have not done anything with these so it *may* not be possible but at least worth investigating

Comment: Well, when I say considerably, I mean 3x the images at least. It may only be a few hundred more KBs, but it's still a far from ideal solution. Is there really no way to overlay graph elements? Maybe I should composite images in code to create a new drawable?